# Akka.net remoting over Docker containers: client randomly fails to connect to host

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, akka.net

There is a simple host with a TestActor that only writes a string it receives to the console:

```
using (var actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("host", HoconLoader.FromFile("config.hocon")))
{
    var testActor = actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<TestActor>(), "TestActor");

    Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for requests...");

    while (true)
    {
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    }
}
```

On the other side there is a simple client that selects the remote actor and passes a TestMessage to it, then waits on an ask without a timeout specified.

```
using (var actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("client", HoconLoader.FromFile("config.hocon")))
{
    var testActor = actorSystem.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://host@host:8081/user/TestActor");

    Console.WriteLine($"Sending message...");

    testActor.Ask(new TestMessage($"Message")).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine($"Message ACKed.");
}
```

The client and the host are deployed on two Docker containers (*docker-compose*), whose network configuration is as follows (*docker network inspect ...*):

```
[
    {
        "Name": "akkaremotetest_default",
        "Id": "4995d7e340e09e4babcca7dc02ddf4f68f70761746c1246d66eaf7ee40ccec89",
        "Created": "2018-07-21T07:55:39.3534215Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "6040c260c5195d2fe350bf3c89b5f9ede8a65d44da6adb48817fbef266a99e07": {
                "Name": "akkaremotetest_host_1",
                "EndpointID": "a6220a6fee071a29b83e30f9aeb9b9e7ec5008f04f593ff3fb2464477a7e54aa",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a97078c28c7d221c2c9af948fe36b72590251be69e06d0e66eafd2c74f416037": {
                "Name": "akkaremotetest_client_1",
                "EndpointID": "39bcb8b1047ad666d9c568ee968602b3a93edb4ac2151ba9c3f3c02359ef84f2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**When the containers are started, the result is one of the following:**

- **the client succeeds with the Ask, the actor writes received message to the console, and the client confirms success**,
- **the client hangs forever, the actor never receives the message, timeout does not occur**.

The problem is that the latter happens most of the time, but only when the host and the client are deployed on Docker containers. When run independently, there are no communication issues.

I think I tried everything without results, and I don't know what else I could do to investigate why the Ask of the client lasts forever, with no errors logged by any of these two actor systems.

Here is the Docker configuration (yml):

```
version: '2'

services:

  host:
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        PROJECT_DIR: Host
        PROJECT_NAME: Host
        WAIT_FOR_HOST: 0
    restart: on-failure

  client:
    depends_on:
      - host
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        PROJECT_DIR: Client
        PROJECT_NAME: Client
        WAIT_FOR_HOST: 1
    restart: on-failure

  tcpdump:
    image: kaazing/tcpdump
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./tcpdump:/tcpdump
```

Here is the configuration of the client system (config.hocon):

```
akka {     
    actor {
        provider = remote
    }

    remote {
        dot-netty.tcp {
            enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
            hostname = client
            port = 8082
        }
    }

    stdout-loglevel = DEBUG
    loglevel = DEBUG
    log-config-on-start = on        

    actor {      
        creation-timeout = 20s  
        debug {  
              receive = on 
              autoreceive = on
              lifecycle = on
              event-stream = on
              unhandled = on
              fsm = on
              event-stream = on
              log-sent-messages = on
              log-received-messages = on
              router-misconfiguration = on
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration of the host system (config.hocon):

```
akka {     
    actor {
        provider = remote
    }

    remote {
        dot-netty.tcp {
            enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
            hostname = host
            port = 8081
        }
    }

    stdout-loglevel = DEBUG
    loglevel = DEBUG
    log-config-on-start = on        

    actor {        
        creation-timeout = 20s  
        debug {  
              receive = on 
              autoreceive = on
              lifecycle = on
              event-stream = on
              unhandled = on
              fsm = on
              event-stream = on
              log-sent-messages = on
              log-received-messages = on
              router-misconfiguration = on
        }
    }
}
```

Following the documentation concerning [Akka remote configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/java/remoting.html#remote-configuration), I attempted to change the client configuration like this:

```
remote {
    dot-netty.tcp {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]

        hostname = 172.19.0.3
        port = 8082

        bind-hostname = client
        bind-port = 8082 
    }
}
```

and the host configuration by analogy:

```
remote {
    dot-netty.tcp {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]

        hostname = 172.19.0.2
        port = 8081

        bind-hostname = host
        bind-port = 8081 
    }
}
```

with a slight change in actor selection as well:

```
var testActor = actorSystem.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://host@172.19.0.2:8081/user/TestActor");
```

Unfortunately this has not helped at all (nothing has changed).

In the logs that are generated during the process, there is a crucial entry that is generated by the host system. Only when it appears, the communication is successful (but most often it does not):

```
[DEBUG][07/21/2018 09:42:50][Thread 0006][remoting] Associated [akka.tcp://host@host:8081] <- akka.tcp://client@client:8082
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

**-- EDIT --**

I added the *tcpdump* section to yml and opened the generated dump file in Wireshark. I also added a 5-second timeout to waiting on ask. It is hard for me to interpret the results, but here is what I got on a failed connection attempt:

```
172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: SYN
172.19.0.2 -> 172.19.0.3: SYN, ACK

172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: ACK

[a 5-second period of silence (waiting till timeout)]

172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: FIN, ACK

172.19.0.2 -> 172.19.0.3: ACK
172.19.0.2 -> 172.19.0.3: FIN, ACK

172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: ACK
```

[image: A failed attempt]

and here is what happens when connection succeeds:

```
172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: SYN
172.19.0.2 -> 172.19.0.3: SYN, ACK

172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: ACK
172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: PSH, ACK

172.19.0.2 -> 172.19.0.3: ACK
172.19.0.2 -> 172.19.0.3: PSH, ACK

172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: ACK
172.19.0.3 -> 172.19.0.2: PSH, ACK
```

[image: A successful attempt]

Versions:

- Akka.NET 1.3.8
- .NET Core 2.1.1
- Docker 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
- Docker-compose 1.21.1, build 7641a569

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to find out if the issue is in the client or server.  Check the start of the connection and the ACK of the connection to see if the connection completes.  Then check to see if the message is sent and if the server ACKs the message.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added TCP dump to my question. I can see that on the failed attempt there is silence after the client sends an ACK to the server. Five seconds later the client sends FIN to close the connection (because I specified a 5-second timeout now for the ask operation). On the successful attempt the communication starts immediately after the client sends an ACK to the server. I'm not sure what else to check to understand what happens. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Look at the errors in the when it fails.  You are getting out-of-order messages.  You may have a routing loop or duplicate IP addresses.  May not be your software.  Possible duplicate IP addresses in your network.  The subnet/gateway in your configuration may be wrong.  I would use from cmd.exe ping to debug the network.  The docker configuration IP addresses should not be set to any IP that already exist.  Do a ping to 172.19.0 1,2,3 and see if you get any responses where the docker is not running.

Comment: I pinged all three of them, and none was pingable. But I also attempted to define a bridge network manually with a custom subnet 192.168.10.0/8, and a gateway 192.168.10.1. The gateway address was pingable, but the addresses of the two containers were not (.2, .3). Tracert 192.168.10.1 shows: 192.168.100.1 (my local network gateway) -> 10.1.9.1 -> 10.0.0.249 -> 10.0.0.236 -> 192.168.10.1.

Comment: IP routing uses both the IP and the mask.  If you have two masks 255.255.0.0 and 255.255.255.0 routing uses the most restrictive mask which is the 2nd mask.  The /8 is an 8 bit mask which is the first mask.  The mask for 10.0.0.249 and 10.0.0.236 have to be made right for the routing to work.  So make mask for both 255.255.255.240.  Which allows 16 IP addresses to pass.  10.0.0.249 which will allow 240-255 to pass.  And for 236 will allow 224-239 to pass.  But then you cannot get to 192.168,10.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I changed the subnet IP to 10.0.0.240/28 and gateway to 10.0.0.241, with .242 and .243 assigned to the host and the client. Now all three of them are pingable. Tracert 10.0.0.241 returns 192.168.100.1 -> 10.1.9.1 -> 10.0.0.241, and tracert 10.0.0.242 returns 192.168.100.1 -> 10.1.9.1 -> 10.0.0.249 -> 10.0.0.242. Still, however, out-of-order packets appear in the TCP dump.

Comment: The out-of-order packets may occur in local networks where the times between packets are very small.  Since you fixed the IP addresses are you still still have the intermittent issue with connecting?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the issue still occurs after fixing the addresses, but as my colleague discovered, it turns out the reason is somewhere else (please see my own answer). Thank you for devoting your time to this problem. I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue stems from the fact that the projects are dependent on .NET Core 2.1 which Akka does not support yet according to [this](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/3506):

> We don't officially support .NET Core 2.1 yet. Heck, we aren't even on
>   netstandard 2.0 yet (although work is underway). But thanks for
>   confirming that there are indeed issues :)

After switching to .NET Core 2.0, I can no longer reproduce described issue.