# Docker compose and out-of-order TCP packets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tcp, packets

There are two Docker containers with the following configuration:

```
version: '2'

services:

  host:
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        PROJECT_DIR: Host
        PROJECT_NAME: Host
        WAIT_FOR_HOST: 0
    restart: on-failure

  client:
    depends_on:
      - host
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        PROJECT_DIR: Client
        PROJECT_NAME: Client
        WAIT_FOR_HOST: 1
    restart: on-failure

  tcpdump:
    image: kaazing/tcpdump
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./tcpdump:/tcpdump
```

Applications started on both of them communicate over TCP/IP.

Here is the network configuration:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "akkaremotetest_default",
        "Id": "4995d7e340e09e4babcca7dc02ddf4f68f70761746c1246d66eaf7ee40ccec89",
        "Created": "2018-07-21T07:55:39.3534215Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "6040c260c5195d2fe350bf3c89b5f9ede8a65d44da6adb48817fbef266a99e07": {
                "Name": "akkaremotetest_host_1",
                "EndpointID": "a6220a6fee071a29b83e30f9aeb9b9e7ec5008f04f593ff3fb2464477a7e54aa",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a97078c28c7d221c2c9af948fe36b72590251be69e06d0e66eafd2c74f416037": {
                "Name": "akkaremotetest_client_1",
                "EndpointID": "39bcb8b1047ad666d9c568ee968602b3a93edb4ac2151ba9c3f3c02359ef84f2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

When I analyse network communication in Wireshark, I can see multiple out-of-order TCP packets.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions why that happens and how to fix it? This could be a possible solution to my other problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454373/akka-net-remoting-over-docker-containers-client-randomly-fails-to-connect-to-ho).

Answer (score 1):

Can you look at the MAC addresses of the packets? If you look closely packet 77 and packet 78 have similar payloads. There is a possibility, the containers are sending out the packets with the MAC address of the bridge and the bridge is routing the packet.

`ip route` inside the containers can confirm if the communication between the packets is happening via routing or bridging.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The source of both the packets is 02:42:ac:13:00:03. When I tracert the IP address of the client or the host, one of the hops is the bridge.

Comment: It turns out the issue I asked about here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454373/akka-net-remoting-over-docker-containers-client-randomly-fails-to-connect-to-ho/51468186#51468186) is solved, and the ordering of TCP packets has nothing to do with it. Therefore I think we can close the current topic.